# How to prove this sequent by natural deduction?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

How do I prove

$$\exists x\exists y(S(x,y)\lor S(y,x))\vdash\exists x\exists y S(x,y)$$

by natural deduction?

I've written follows:

1$\quad\quad\exists x\exists y(S(x,y)\lor S(y,x))\quad$ assumption

2$\quad x_0$

3$\quad\quad\exists y(S(x_0,y)\lor S(y,x_0))\quad$ assumption

4$\quad y_0$

5$\quad\quad S(x_0,y_0)\lor S(y_0,x_0)\quad$ assumption

And I stuck here.
Can somebody give me some advice?
Thanks a lot.

I got the hint, is this right:
[image: myAnswer]

Comment: What version of $\exists$-intro and $\exists$-elim rules are you using?  Looks like it might be based on "constants" .

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

From 5) we need $\lor$-elim (or [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination)):

5a) From $S(x_0,y_0)$ we derive $\exists x \exists y S(x,y)$ by $\exists$-intro twice.

5b) From $S(y_0,x_0)$ we derive $\exists x \exists y S(x,y)$ by $\exists$-intro twice.

Comment: Hey, I just got the hint, am I right?

Comment: @walkcc - Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Case I $S(x_{0},y_{0})$. Then $\exists y S(x_{0},y)$, so $\exists x\exists y S(x,y)$, done.

Case II $S(y_{0},x_{0})$. Then $\exists y S(y_{0},y)$, so $\exists x\exists yS(x,y)$, done.